# Deploy to artifactory based on the data from repo

Tags: git, artifactory, gogs

Would like to know how can use curl to get file from a repository for instance gogs and push to another repository for instance artifacotry. I saw we can use -T which can get from url. The below code works however, it will get the local file test.tx. I want to get it from repo and deploy to artifacotry

```
curl -X PUT -T test.txt -u username:password "http://123.22.91.243:8080/artifactory/local-file/MyFiles/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a file from a repo through curl is not a feature of `git` alone, it is a feature of web based git servers, like `github`, `gitlab`, or `gogs`.

These servers generally allow you to browse to any file you want within the repo.

For example : on the gitub mirror of [the git repo](https://github.com/git/git), you can click your way to the `checkout.c` file :
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/checkout.c
and then click on the `[Raw]` button :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/builtin/checkout.c

That's a url you can also access using `curl`.

As it indicates, the above url targets the `master` branch (which can evolve in time), you can find a way to target a commit identified by its fixed `sha1` :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/385c171a018f2747b329bcfa6be8eda1709e5abd/builtin/checkout.c

Browse on your own server to find out how urls are built.